# Is Isles' theorem 2.6 correct?

Tags: logic, set-theory

In "Regular Ordinals and Normal Forms", Theorem 2.6, David Isles claims
that Bachmann proves that the sequence of normal functions generated by a
Bachmann collection has property (6).  Firstly, Bachmann does not prove
this.  Secondly, I haven't found a proof.  Thirdly, it does hold for some
"natural" Bachmann collections.  The question is, is this statement correct?

Isles refers to p. 130 of Bachmann, where this property is numbered 2) b).
For a translation, see page 20 of the translation referenced below.
Bachmann in fact assumes that this property holds for the collection
${\mathfrak F}$.

I have constructed a Bachmann collection of interest in a paper referenced
below.  I call the property "P1", and prove that it holds for this
particular Bachmann collection.  I have been unable to prove that it
follows from the axioms for a Bachmann collection.  Section 3 contains
some general lemmas of interest.  The following may also be observed:

Given a built-up scheme, if $t_\xi\lt u\leq t_{\xi+1}$ where $u$ is a limit
ordinal then not only does $t_\xi\leq u_0$ hold, but in fact
$t_\xi\prec u_0$ holds.  This may be seen from the proof of theorem 1.

Suppose (I) $t\xrightarrow\oplus t_0$ holds for all limit ordinals $t$.
Then if $t_\xi\lt u\leq t_{\xi+1}$ where $u$ is a limit ordinal then
$u\xrightarrow\oplus u_0\xrightarrow* t_\xi$.  From this, property
(6) holds.

As noted in the paper, (I) holds in various "natural" Bachmann collections.

- Self-contained statement

In response to Asaf's comment below here is a self-contained statement,
in the terminology of my paper.  A scheme over a regular uncountable
ordinal $\Omega$ (e.g. $\aleph_1$) of length $\sigma<\Omega^+$ is a
system of fundamental sequences $\alpha_\xi:\xi\lt  D_\alpha$ for limit
ordinals $\alpha<\sigma$, such that $D_\alpha<\Omega$ if $\alpha$ has
cofinality $<\Omega$, and $D_\alpha=\Omega$ if $\alpha$ has cofinality
$\Omega$.  This specifies an iteration, starting with a club subset of
$\Omega$ (e.g. the powers of $\omega$), applying the fixed point operation,
intersection, and diagonal intersection at successor stages, limit stages
of cofinality $<\Omega$, and diagonal intersection at stages of cofinality
$\Omega$.  Let $R_\alpha$ denote the (club) subset at stage $\alpha$.

A scheme is built-up if whenever $\alpha_\xi<\beta\leq\alpha_{\xi+1}$ and
$\beta$ is a limit ordinal then $\alpha_\xi\leq\beta_0$.  A scheme has
property P2 if whenever $\alpha$ and $\xi$ are limit ordinals then
$(\alpha_\xi)_\delta=\alpha_\delta$.  (A Bachmann collection is more or
less a scheme with these two properties).  A scheme has property P1 if
whenever $\alpha_\xi<\beta\leq\alpha_{\xi+1}$ and $\beta$ is a limit ordinal
then $R_\beta\subseteq R_{\alpha_\xi+1}$.

The question is, does property P1 follow from the requirements that the
scheme be built-up and have property P2?

- References:

Bachmann:
 H.\ Bachmann, Die Normalfunktionen und das Problem der ausgezeichnetenFolgen
   von Ordnungszahlen,
 http://www.ngzh.ch/archiv/1950_95/95_2/95_14.pdf

Bachmann translation:
 http://arxiv.org/abs/1903.04609

Isles:
 D Isles, Regular ordinals and normal forms,
 https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0049237X08707638

My paper:
 https://www.researchgate.net/publication333058459_An_Ordinal_Larger_Than_the_Bachmann-Howard_Ordinal

Comment: You see why this question is completely unanswerable to anyone not holding those references, right?